# How can I reverse of flow of Option Monad?

Tags: scala, scala-option

say, I have a bunch of "validation" functions that return None if there is no error, otherwise it return  Some(String) specifying the error message.  Something like the following ...

```
def validate1:Option[String] 
def validate2:Option[String]
def validate3:Option[String]
```

I am going to call them in a sequence and as soon as one returns Some(String), I stop and return the same. If it returns None, I go to the next until the sequence is over. If all of them return None, I return None.

I would like to glue them together in a "for expression". Something like ...

```
for( a <- validate1; b <- validate2; c <- validate3) yield None;
```

However, Option flows exactly the opposite what I want here. It stops at None and follows with Some(String).

How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 17):

You could just chain the calls together with the **orElse** method on Option

```
validate1 orElse validate2 orElse validate3
```

or you could run a fold over a collection of validate methods converted to functions

```
val vlist= List(validate1 _, validate2 _, validate3 _)

vlist.foldLeft(None: Option[String]) {(a, b) => if (a == None) b() else a}
```

Comment: +1 I'd even merge those two solutions to gain shorter and more readable form: l.foldLeft(None: Option[String]) {(a, b) => a orElse b()}

Comment: I like the orElse chaining. Thanks Don.

Comment: @mcveat, that's a nice refinement, @sanjib, it was a good question, orElse seems to come up quite frequently on SO.

Comment: You could also use `Stream` + `find`: `(validate1 #:: validate2 #:: validate3 #:: Stream.empty).find(_.isDefined).flatMap(identity)`. I would've used `flatten` at the end there, but it comes out as a list.

Answer (score 3):

The [**scalaz**](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/) library has a type called `Validation` which allows for some incredible gymnastics with building both errors and success. For example, suppose you have a few methods which can either return a *failure* message or some successful outcome (A/B/C):

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
def fooA : ValidationNEL[String, A]
def fooB : ValidationNEL[String, B]
def fooC : ValidationNEL[String, C]
```

These can be used with the applicative functor to chain the calls together:

```
(foo1 <|**|> (foo2, foo3)) match {
  case Success( (a, b, c) ) => //woot
  case Failure(msgs)        => //erk
}
```

Note that if any one of `foo1/2/3` fails, then the whole composition fails with a *non-empty list* (NEL) of failure messages. If more than one fails, you get all failure messages.

It's a killer app. Examples of how tor return a success and failure are as follows

```
def foo1 : ValidationNEL[String, Int] = 1.success
def foo2 : ValidationNEL[String, Double] = "some error msg".failNel
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just combine the iterators together and then take the first element? Something like:

```
scala> def validate1: Option[String] = {println("1"); None}
scala> def validate2: Option[String] = {println("2"); Some("error")}
scala> def validate3: Option[String] = {println("3"); None}
scala> (validate1.iterator ++ validate2.iterator ++ validate3.iterator).next
1
2
res5: String = error
```

Comment: The last line could be simplified a little bit: `(validate1 ++ validate2 ++ validate3).head`

Comment: I don't think you want to drop the `.iterator` calls - then you'll always call all the validate methods instead of only calling methods until one of them returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might benefit from using Lift's [Box](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Box), which has `Full` (i.e. `Some`), `Empty` (i.e. `None`) and `Failure` (an `Empty` with a reason why it's empty and that can be chained). David Pollak has a [good blog post](http://lift.la/scala-option-lift-box-and-how-to-make-your-co) introducing it. In short, you might do something like this (not tested):

```
def validate1: Box[String]
def validate2: Box[String]
def validate3: Box[String]
val validation = for (
  validation1 <- validate1 ?~ "error message 1"
  validation2 <- validate2 ?~ "error message 2"
  validation3 <- validate3 ?~ "error message 3"
) yield "overall success message"
```

This isn't any shorter than the original example but it's, in my opinion, a bit more logical, with the result of a successful validation in a `Full` and a failed validation in `Failure`.

However, we can get smaller. First, since our validation function return `Box[String]`, they can return `Failure`s themselves and we don't need to transform `Empty` to `Failure` ourselves:

```
val validation = for (
  validation1 <- validate1
  validation2 <- validate2
  validation3 <- validate3
) yield "overall success message"
```

But, `Box` also has an `or` method that returns the same `Box` if it is `Full` or the other `Box` if it is not. This would give us:

val validation = validate1 or validate2 or validate3

However, that line stops at the first validation *success*, not the first failure. It might make sense to make another method that does what you want (perhaps called `unless`?) though I can't say that it would really be much more useful than the for comprehension approach.

However, here's a little library pimping that does it:

```
scala> class Unless[T](a: Box[T]) {
     | def unless(b: Box[T]) = {
     | if (a.isEmpty) { a }
     | else b
     | }
     | }
defined class Unless

scala> implicit def b2U[T](b: Box[T]): Unless[T] = new Unless(b)
b2U: [T](b: net.liftweb.common.Box[T])Unless[T]

scala> val a = Full("yes")                                      
a: net.liftweb.common.Full[java.lang.String] = Full(yes)

scala> val b = Failure("no")                                    
b: net.liftweb.common.Failure = Failure(no,Empty,Empty)

scala> val c = Full("yes2")                                     
c: net.liftweb.common.Full[java.lang.String] = Full(yes2)

scala> a unless b
res1: net.liftweb.common.Box[java.lang.String] = Failure(no,Empty,Empty)

scala> a unless b unless c
res2: net.liftweb.common.Box[java.lang.String] = Failure(no,Empty,Empty)

scala> a unless c unless b
res3: net.liftweb.common.Box[java.lang.String] = Failure(no,Empty,Empty)

scala> a unless c
res4: net.liftweb.common.Box[java.lang.String] = Full(yes2)
```

This is a quick hack based upon my limited understanding of Scala's type system, as you can see in the following error:

```
scala> b unless a
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : net.liftweb.common.Full[java.lang.String]
 required: net.liftweb.common.Box[T]
       b unless a
                ^
```

However, that should be enough to get you on the right track.

Of course the [Lift ScalaDocs](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/index.html) have more information on [Box](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/common/Box.html).